# 'rich:component' not found: a4j:ajax with a composite component

Tags: jsf, namespaces, richfaces, el, composite

I've built a simple composite component - a "richer" commandLink. I want it to support the `clientBehavior`, but when there is a `<a4j:ajax>` attached to the component I sometimes get the exception: `ELException: Function 'rich:component' not found`

It only comes when I use `#{rich:component('...')}` inside any attribute of `<a4j:ajax>`. For example `oncomplete="#{rich:component('...')}.show()"`

Edit: **I am getting a Server error, not a JavaScript error.**

The composite component (simplified):

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="style" />
    <composite:clientBehavior name="click" event="action" targets="commandLink" default="true"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:commandLink id="commandLink" style="#{cc.attrs.style}">
        <!-- my custom component content -->
    </h:commandLink>
</composite:implementation>
```

The problematic use of this component looks like this:

```
<myLib:commandLink value="Custom CmdLink">
    <a4j:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"
        oncomplete="#{rich:component('myEditPopup')}"/>
</myLib:commandLink>
```

But the following code works like a charm:

```
<h:commandLink value="test">
    <a4j:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"
        oncomplete="#{rich:component('myEditPopup')}.show()"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Edit: **This one works too:**

```
<a4j:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('myEditPopup')}.show()">
    <myLib:commandLink value="label"/>
</a4j:ajax>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in Mojarra (we have been using the version 2.1.6), that EL lost the namespace "rich".
A working workaround was to declare the namespace in the a4j:ajax tag for each use:

```
                <myLib:commandLink value="Show">
                    <a4j:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
                              oncomplete="#{rich:component('myEditPopup')}.show()"/>
                </myLib:commandLink>
```

After updating Mojarra to 2.1.26 the problem is gone and no needs for this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing `{` in your el, you will get the error `rich:component not found`.

For `a4j:commandButton`

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Show" oncomplete="#{rich:component('chargePointDetailPopup')}.show()"/>
```

For a4j:ajax in commandLink

```
<h:commandLink value="Show">
    <a4j:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" oncomplete="#rich:component('chargePointDetailPopup')}.show()"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Make sure to `rich:popupPanel`

```
<rich:popupPanel id="chargePointDetailPopup">
......
</rich:popupPanel>
```

For more [Reference](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&skin=blueSky)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply - I've cut out a little bit too much from my code - in the original code there is the missing "{" (is fixed now). What I am getting is a Server-error, not a JavaScript error.